# Does this threat still exist: Linux keylogger without root privileges

Tags: security, malware

https://superuser.com/questions/301646/linux-keylogger-without-root-or-sudo-is-it-real

Or it's long gone as most of the new distros implement SELinux by default

Comment: This has nothing to do with SELinux—and if you read the answers to that question, they give you easy tests to do on your own to check. But yes it still exists, its how X works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't watched the video, so I'm responding to the SU thread rather than the video it references.

If an attacker can run code on your machine as your user, then they can log your key presses.

Well, duh. All the applications you're running have access to your key presses. If you're typing stuff in your web browser, your web browser has access to your key presses.

Ah, you say, but what about logging key presses in another application? As long as the other application is running on the same X server, they can still be logged. X11 doesn't attempt to isolate applications — that's not its job. X11 allows programs to define global shortcuts, which is useful for input methods, to define macros, etc.

If the attacker can run code as your user, he can also read and modify your files, and cause all kinds of other harm.

This is not a threat. It's part of the normal expectations of a working system. If you allow an attacker to run code on your machine, your machine isn't safe anymore. It's like if you open your front door and allow an axe murderer in: if you then get cleaved in two, it's not because your front door is insecure.

SELinux is irrelevant here. SELinux attempts to contain unauthorized behavior, but after the initial exploit (which is not within SELinux's domain), everything is authorized behavior.

The keylogger can only log keys pressed by the infected user. (At least as long as the infected user doesn't type the sudo password.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Following attack can be performed:

1. A user runs an untrusted application
2. This application starts to intercept all the key strokes
3. User runs `sudo command` in their terminal
4. Password is acquired by the application and an adversary has the full control over the system